# How to use embedded functions(One Scroll Page by Pete - peachananr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

recently I am working on a page using this awesome plugin:

https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

However I am not familiar with JavaScript so I will be obliged if someone could explain to me few things:

1. I'd like to combine one-scroll-page behaviour with anchor scrolling, simple example:

   `function scrollContent(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top }, 1000 );
    }`

as far as I know there is an embedded function called "$.fn.moveTo(page_index)"(see plugin link) but I wasn't able to use it successfully.

1. I'd like to turn a slider when leaving page #1 to save resources, slider launches with function:

`$('#da-slider').cslider({
                    autoplay    : true,
                    interval    : 8000,
                });`

tried to simply turn off autoplay by messing with callbacks but it turned out to be bad solution:

`$(".main").onepage_scroll({
   sectionContainer: "section",     // sectionContainer accepts any kind of selector in case you don't want to use section
   easing: "ease",                  // Easing options accepts the CSS3 easing animation such "ease", "linear", "ease-in", 
                                    // "ease-out", "ease-in-out", or even cubic bezier value such as "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.420, 1.310)"
   animationTime: 1000,             // AnimationTime let you define how long each section takes to animate
   pagination: true,                // You can either show or hide the pagination. Toggle true for show, false for hide.
   updateURL: true,                // Toggle this true if you want the URL to be updated automatically when the user scroll to each page.
   beforeMove: function(index) {},  // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called before the page moves.
   afterMove: function(#1) {
$('#da-slider').cslider({
                    autoplay    : off,
                    interval    : 8000,
                });
},   // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called after the page moves.
   loop: true,                     // You can have the page loop back to the top/bottom when the user navigates at up/down on the first/last page.
   keyboard: true,                  // You can activate the keyboard controls
   responsiveFallback: 600,        // You can fallback to normal page scroll by defining the width of the browser in which
                                    // you want the responsive fallback to be triggered. For example, set this to 600 and whenever 
                                    // the browser's width is less than 600, the fallback will kick in.
   direction: "horizontal"            // You can now define the direction of the One Page Scroll animation. Options available are "vertical" and "horizontal". The default value is "vertical".

   });`

Every tip, even link to jquery tutorial will be very helpfull. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

```
$("#your-div-id").on("click", function(){$(".main").moveTo(2);});
```